# Break array into 4 arrays and store those arrays within a new array javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array which I would like to break into 4 pieces (4 arrays), and then store those 4 arrays into another array.

This is what I have so far:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

while(a.length) {
     a.splice(0,3); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good start. You also need an array to put the arrays in:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var result = [];

while (a.length > 0) {
  result.push(a.splice(0,3));
}
```

(Using `while (a.length)` works fine, but I like to use the more specific condition `while (a.length > 0)`.)